# async script attribute vs async property?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-async

The `async` attribute , is a more recent feature of HTML5,
 which indicates that the downloaded file won’t call `document.write` and can be downloaded as the page is being processed

But I've heard that there’s *another way* to load scripts asynchronously that’s backward compatible
*with older browsers*.

It turns out that I  can re-create the behavior achieved by the `async` attribute by dynamically
creating a script DOM element in JavaScript and appending it to the page.

Example :

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://camerastork.com/widget.js?product=1234';
script.async = true
...
```

So if it's for old browsers , which don't support `async`-- how can it be  - that I can still use `.async` property ?

Comment: In your example, don't forget to actually add `script` to something (e.g., `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode.appendChild(script);`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes its a part from a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `async` attribute/property is older than you think it is (at least in some browser lineages). But the real reason this works is that the majority of browsers have always treated all `script` elements added to the DOM via `createElement` / `appendChild` as "asynchronous" (without requiring `script.async = true`). There were only a couple of browsers, years ago, that treated them synchronously (didn't execute the next line of code until the script had been fetched and executed), and the browsers in question have since updated their behavior.

Comment: well I read it [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DPLr5.png) (which states that it is a more recent deature of html5....). but It's weird that MDN doesnt states its an html 5 feature

Comment: @RoyiNamir: A lot of HTML5 is codifying, documenting, and standardizing what at least some browsers have been doing for years. This is an example of that.

Comment: So if I create dynamic script , should I or should I not add async property ? and what if I want to add async attribute ? Im confused,

Comment: @RoyiNamir: If you create a script via `createElement` and add it to the DOM, with modern browsers, it doesn't matter whether you set `script.async = true` or not, it will be executed asynchronously. With some older browsers (Firefox 3.x, for instance), scripts added to the DOM that way were executed in order, but that was never common behavior, and those browsers stopped doing it. Setting `script.async = true;` is harmless, but unnecessary with modern browsers. Re the async attribute, the `async` property is a *reflected attribute* (like `id` is for the `id` attribute).

Comment: Q : You said : _With some older browsers (Firefox 3.x, for instance), scripts added to the DOM that way were executed in order_.... But how can it be ? If I create  a script element ( when im at the end of `</body>`) and attach it to the `head` , the `head` was **already parsed**. so what order are we talking about ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I think they did it in the order they were added to the DOM, but I have to admit I never played with it. Until recently I thought elements added that way had always been asynchronous, happened to run across that old info a week or so back.

Comment: If I add a script via `...createElement('script')` and I'm setting `script.async =false` and I append it to the `head`. logically , the script should not run at all ! because the interpreter has **already passed the head section**. ( and I set `async` to `false` which means `synchronously`). but the script DOES run. what is going on here ? . ( I do `createElement` at the end of the `body` which is after the `head`)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That JSBin doesn't make any sense. You're creating a script element, then setting its `async` property to `false`, then setting its `async` property to `undefined` because you're running an `alert` and assigning the result of the alert to the property. Then you're finding the first `script` *already* in the document and re-appending it to `head`, which is a no-op.

Comment: @what was I thinking .... sorry here is the jsbin http://jsbin.com/EraMuKE/10/edit

Comment: @RoyiNamir: `script.text = alert('lala');;` still *calls* `alert` and assigns its return value to `script.text`.

Comment: I just don't understand how scripts which appended dynamically to the head , can be executed - if the interpreter has already passed the location

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Re your question: I would have said logically, the script should be executed before the `appendChild` call returns, if it doesn't have a `src`. You can find all the gory details [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) (and they are *gory*). In my experience, if the script wasn't inserted by the HTML or XML parser, the `async` has no effect at all: If the script has a `src`, it's run asynchronously; if not, it's run right away.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: *"For example - how could this be working ?"* Because appending a `script` element to the document runs the script. Side note: ***Please*** don't use `alert` for this stuff. `alert` has all kinds of side-effects. Use `console.log`. I have to get back to work, best,

Comment: TJ , but the interpreter has already passed the head location.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: `alert` and `confirm` *mostly* stop the script interpreter in its tracks. This frequently changes what would have happened if you didn't use `alert` or `confirm`. And that "mostly" can bite you.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The *interpreter* doesn't know or care about `head`. The *parser* did, at one point. But the act of appending a script to the document (anywhere) makes the script run. Again: See the specification. Again, I have to get back to work. You really should have posted a question about this so it would get attention from more than one person. Best,

Comment: Ok . thanks. I thought that if the parser has already passed the head location . it wont DIGEST it again.and I'm apparently wrong here.