# Why would an external script not be added to DOM?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a third party script dynamically the usual way:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = document.location.protocol+'//path.to.script/script.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

It doesn't work - I don't see the `<script>` tag in the `<head>` tag. When I run the same snippet in the browser console, it's the same - I don't see the `<script>` tag in the `<head>`. When I open the link directly I'm actually seeing the `script.js` file contents. If I change the `s.src` to something else (anything) it adds the `<script>` tag as expected.

What could be preventing from the script being added dynamically?

Comment: Does the script show up in the network tab of the console?

Answer (score 1):

[Some browsers require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901546/async-script-attribute-vs-async-property) `s.async=true;` to be present , when adding dynamically scripts - in order to  auto run.

Try adding it and check again.

Also (best practice tip) , I would suggest you a best practice not to add to head but :

```
 var entry = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 entry.parentNode.insertBefore(script, entry);
```

Also you dont need `document.location.protocol+'//path.to.script/script.js';`

`'//path.to.script/script.js'`  - would do just fine.

this is how google work :

[image]

Comment: Added the `asynch` piece, and changed the injection method to your `entry` thing, still no go :(